# Android Virtual Device is pixelated

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

My AVD's are very pixelated. Does anyone know how to fix this on Windows 10?

[Pixelated Android Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkJ28.png)

Specs of virtual device:

Pixel5 API 31
Graphics: Hardware
MultiCore CPU: 4
RAM: 3GB
VMHeap: 1GB
Internal Storage: 6GB

Android Studio:
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 18, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 3072M
Cores: 16
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, ide.instant.shutdown=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart (212.5744), com.genymotion.idea (1.0.9), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (212.5457.16), org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.7.0-release-281-AS5457.46), io.flutter (68.1.2)